# What is meaning of "where" keyword?

Tags: ios, swift

I couldn't understand exact meaning of this statement.

```
let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper")
```

What is meaning of that?

**Note:** There is no need of `let` use? It makes me confusing.. Is this enough `x where x.hasSuffix("pepper")`? because, `let x` should be already get assigned.?

**Update:**
From @Jacky comment here, it could be meaning same as below.

```
let x = vegetable 
if (x.hasSuffix("pepper")
 ......
```

Comment: @Leandros In that question, they didn't clearly explain `Where`?

Comment: Sure, where is just another requirement in a switch statement, in addition to the switch. Imagine it as an if in a switch.

Comment: I think so , but there is no need of `let` use? It makes me confusing.. Is this enough `x where x.hasSuffix("pepper")`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `where` in that context is used as [pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching). From the example:

```
case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
```

When the suffix of `x` matches `"pepper"` it will set the constant `vegetableComment`:

```
let vegetableComment = "Is it a spicy \(x)?"
```

You can see as well that `x` can´t be "celery", "cucumber" or "watercress", otherwise it would give you a different outcome:

```
case "celery":
    let vegetableComment = "Add some raisins and make ants on a log."
case "cucumber", "watercress":
    let vegetableComment = "That would make a good tea sandwich."
```

Because those cases are before `case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):`. You can try changing the order of them and pass the value "celery" to see a different outcome.

**Edit:**

From my understanding it creates a constant `x` **if** `x`'s suffix is "pepper". The goal of creating this constant, is for you to use it after that:

```
let vegetableComment = "Is it a spicy \(x)?"
```

**Edit 2:**

After a bit more research, that's called value binding and it's described as:

> switch case can bind the value or values it matches to temporary
>   constants or variables, for use in the body of the case. This is known
>   as value binding, because the values are “bound” to temporary
>   constants or variables within the case’s body.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/gb/jEUH0.l

Comment: I think so , but there is no need of `let` use? It makes me confusing.. Is this enough `x where x.hasSuffix("pepper")`? because, `let x` should be already get assigned. Am I right.?

Comment: @Mani I think you need the `let` since you are in fact introducing a new variable `x`. (but I am might be wrong about it).

Comment: It should not be. because nobody won't make this condition with new variable. correct?

Comment: @Mani well actually you do, since you use the `x` after: `let vegetableComment = "Is it a spicy \(x)?"` you see the `x`
 being used `\(x)`.

Comment: hey this is next line, 1) intro here `case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):`  2) used it here 
`let vegetableComment = "Is it a spicy \(x)?"`. this is correct.

Comment: Yes and that's why `x` is created, so it can be used after.

Comment: @JackyBoy Ya this make sense. According to second edit, my updation would be correct.?.

Comment: `"The goal of creating this constant, is for you to use it after that:"`. Well you can just refer to `vegetable`, the variable is still accessible...

Answer (score 7):

```
case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper")
```

The simple explanation is that you cannot match a case, that is of type `String`, with `.hasSuffix()` because it returns a `Bool`. So, they give you this `where` pattern matching keyword to use. It works like this:

1. `let x` copies the String value you are passing into the switch to the constant x.
2. `where` is a boolean evaluation that will only let the case complete the match if it is given a true bool, just like an `if` block.
3. `hasSuffix()` returns the bool required by `where`.

If your string variable passed into the switch is `var foo`. You can literally do this instead:

```
case foo where foo.hasSuffix("pepper")
```

You can pass a true bool to where like this and it would work, uselessly:

```
case foo where true
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a larger view of the code:

```
switch vegetable {

... omissis ...

case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
    let vegetableComment = "Is it a spicy \(x)?"
default:
    let vegetableComment = "Everything tastes good in soup."
}
```

What it does is match the value of `vegetable` assigning it to `x` and testing if it has suffix `"pepper"`. If the match succeeds it executes the case block `let vegetableComment = "Is it a spicy \(x)?"` otherwise it continues with the next test (which in this case is a `default:`).

Note that the `let` is necessary. It means that you are binding a new variable `x`.

Also note that it's not the same as

```
case let x:
   if (x.hasSuffix("pepper")
      ...
```

as this always succeeds and enters the case block, while using the `where` clause means that if the condition is not satisfied the match fails and the next `case` (or `default`) shall be tried.

Comment: Yes. You say it may be like a case with an if in the code block. But it's not the same thing. The if must be in the where clause for the match to be able to fail. If it's in the code block the test is done too late and even if the condition is false the case pattern matched has already succeeded.

Comment: I don't mean, write code as said. Instead, it give meaning as same.

Comment: `let x` is not necessary if you replace it with `vegetable`, aka. `case vegetable where vegetable.hasSuffix("pepper"):`

Answer (score 1):

### `Let` is not useful in this example, and can be removed:

I modified the code OP was referring (available in the [GuidedTour](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html) to exclude `let x`, to show that `let x` is **completely useless.** Readability is also improved, as `x` is no longer present. This is at the heart of OP's (Mani) question: why use `let`?  The answer is, **in this case, you shouldn't.**

Using `x` is confusing, what does it mean? And finally, why would you need to redeclare a constant (`vegetable` as `x`), because it is not going to change. It pointless!

```swift
let vegetable = "red pepper"
switch vegetable {
case "celery":
    print("Add some raisins and make ants on a log.")
case "cucumber", "watercress":
    print("That would make a good tea sandwich.")
case vegetable where vegetable.hasSuffix("pepper"):
    print("Is it a spicy \(vegetable)?")
default:
    print("Everything tastes good in soup.")
}
// Prints "Is it a spicy red pepper?"
```

---

### Switch statements, briefly

First of all, the `where` keyword allows you to execute arbitrary code inside each case, so that you can run different code in different case condition. Without this, a switch statement will just check for **equality** between the argument and the case.

**Limited:** each case condition compares the switch statement condition (`age`) to the case expression, because `where` is not used:

```swift
switch age {
case 20:
        print("He is 20")
case 21:
        print("He is 21")
        print("or... he is \(age)")
default:
    print("He is in an unknown age group.")
}
```

**Better:** We can now execute code in the case expression, because where is used (Notice no **let** is used). This allows ranges, and more complex expressions to be used, which will shorten the size of the switch statement:

```swift
switch age {
case let age where age < 20:
    print("He is younger than 20")
case age where 20 < age && age < 30:
    print("He is between 20 and 30")
    print("\(age)")
default:
    print("He is in an unknown age group.")
}
```

**No benefit gained:** There is no use creating a new constant to hold the exact value as the argument to switch:

```swift
switch age {
case let age where age < 20:
    print("He is younger than 20")
case let age_2 where 20 < age_2 && age_2 < 30:
    print("He is between 20 and 30")
    print("\(age == age_2) is True, and will always be True. Useless!")
default:
    print("He is in an unknown age group.")
}
```

So, redeclaring the switch condition (`age` or `vegetable`) using `let x ...` is completely useless.

---

### Where let is actually useful:

`let vegetable` can come in useful here, when we don't have a variable or constant for the value passed into switch:

```swift
func getVegetable() -> String {
    return "Sweet Potato"
}

switch(getVegetable()) {
case "Pepper":
    print("Spicy!")
case let vegetable where vegetable.hasSuffix("Potato"):
    print("eww potatoes!")
default:
    print("Unknown vegetable")
}
```

It is more useful when you want to unpack the argument passed to the switch statement:

```swift
let anotherPoint = (2, 0)
switch anotherPoint {
case (let x, 0):
    print("on the x-axis with an x value of \(x)")
case (0, let y):
    print("on the y-axis with a y value of \(y)")
case let (x, y):
    print("somewhere else at (\(x), \(y))")
}
// Prints "on the x-axis with an x value of 2"
```

[source (read value binding section)](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-XID_153#value%20bindings). It actually allows you to match the rest of the switch argument, and declare a more useful variable.

I would've called this feature **variable unpacking** or **switch unpacking** or **switch unpacking or aliasing** or **partial matching** instead of value binding. When you declare any variable, you are binding a value to that variable too... "value binding" is a meaningless/ broad name.

Answer (score 0):

**"where"** clause introduced in swift 2 but never got a recognition from developers for its usage. It is used for pattern matching and can be used with for-in, switch statements. It is basically a part of control flow and can be used anywhere in your code. Some examples are as follows

```
//Example usage in switch
let yetAnotherPoint = (1, -1)
switch yetAnotherPoint {
case let (x, y) where x == y:
    print("(\(x), \(y)) is on the line x == y")
case let (x, y) where x == -y:
    print("(\(x), \(y)) is on the line x == -y")
case let (x, y):
    print("(\(x), \(y)) is just some arbitrary point")
}

//Example usage in for
let arr = [1,2,3,4]
for value in arr where value != 0 {
    print(value)
}
```